# ZMQ C++ Event Loop Within Class

Tags: c++, event-handling, zeromq

My overall goal in using ZMQ is to avoid having to get into the weeds of asynchronous message passing; and ZMQ seemed like a portable and practical solution. Most of the ZeroMQ docs, however, [like this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp%3amspoller), and many of the other zmq examples I have Googled upon are based on the *helloworld.c* format. That is, they are all simple procedural code inside `int main(){}`.

My problem is that I want to "embed" a zmq "listener" inside a c++ singleton-like class. I want to "listen" for messages and then process them. I'm planning on using zmq's `PUSH` -> `PULL` sockets, on the off chance that matters. What I cannot figure out how to do is to have in internal "event loop".

```
class foomgr {
    public:
        static foomgr& get_foomgr();
    // ...
    private:
        foomgr();
        foomgr(const &foomgr);
    // ...
        listener_() {
            // EVENT LOOP HERE
            // RECV and PROCESS ZMQ MSGS
            // while(true) DOES NOT WORK HERE
        }
    // ...
        zmq::context_t zmqcntx_;
        zmq::socket_t zmqsock_;
        const int zmqsock_linger_ = 1000;
    // ....
}
```

I obviously cannot use the `while(true)` construct in listener, since wherever I call it from will block. Since one of the advantages of using ZMQ is that I do not have to manage "listener" threads myself, it seems silly to have to figure out how create my own thread to wrap listener_ in. I'm lost for solutions.

*Note: I'm a c++ newb, so what might be obvious to most is not to me. Also, I'm trying to use generic "words", not library or language specific to avoid confusion. The code is built with -std=c++11, so those 
constructs are fine.*

Comment: Which thread do you want these event callbacks to be called in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ZMQ C++ library does not implement a listener pattern for message polling. It leaves that task up to you to wrap in your own classes. It does support a non-blocking mode of polling for new messages, however.

So using the right code you can wrap it up in a small loop in a non-blocking fashion.

See this [Polling Example here on GitHub](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/mspoller.cpp) written in C++. Note that its polling from 2 sockets, so you'll need to modify it a little to remove the extra code.

The important part that you'll need to wrap inside your own observer implementation is below:

```
zmq::message_t message;
zmq::poll (&items [0], 2, -1);

if (items [0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
    receiver.recv(&message);
    //  Process task
}
```

Comment: The question asks about the `listener` member function, not the zmq functions. Basically, I am asking if there is any way to "register a listener" with ZMQ so that ZMQ does the `while` loop not my function.

Comment: I also mentioned that I did not find the simplistic "int main(){...}" examples helpful; yet you linked to exactly that without addressing its relevance to this use case. While I appreciate the suggestion, it do not address the quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

Zmq is not thread safe by design (versions up to now). In fact, Zmq stresses:

> Do not use or close sockets except in the thread that created them.
>   PERIOD.

**Callbacks shouldn't be used because the thread calling the callback, will be for sure different from the thread that created the socket, which is forbidden.**

Maybe, you will find useful [zmqHelper](https://github.com/cibercitizen1/zmqHelper), a small library (only two classes and a few functions), to make it easier using Zmq in C++ and to enforce (it is guaranteed) that threads can't share sockets.

In the example sections, you will find how to do the most frequent tasks.

Hope it helps.

Code snippet: polling using zmqHelper in a ROUTER-DEALER broker.

```
zmq::context_t theContext {1}; // 1 thread in the socket 
SocketAdaptor< ZMQ_ROUTER > frontend_ROUTER {theContext};
SocketAdaptor< ZMQ_DEALER > backend_DEALER {theContext};

frontend_ROUTER.bind ("tcp://*:8000");
backend_DEALER.bind ("tcp://*:8001");

while (true) {

  std::vector<std::string> lines;

  // 
  //  wait (blocking poll) for data in any socket
  // 
  std::vector< zmqHelper::ZmqSocketType * > list
    = {  frontend_ROUTER.getZmqSocket(),  backend_DEALER.getZmqSocket() };

  zmqHelper::ZmqSocketType *  from = zmqHelper::waitForDataInSockets ( list );

  // 
  //  there is data, where is it from?
  // 
  if ( from ==  frontend_ROUTER.getZmqSocket() ) {
    // from frontend, read ...
    frontend_ROUTER.receiveText (lines);

    // ... and resend
    backend_DEALER.sendText( lines );
  }
  else if ( from ==  backend_DEALER.getZmqSocket() ) {
    // from backend, read ...
    backend_DEALER.receiveText (lines);

    // ... and resend
    frontend_ROUTER.sendText( lines );
  } 
  else if ( from == nullptr ) {
    std::cerr << "Error in poll ?\n";
  }

} // while (true)
```